# NSAttributedString keeps its attribute after its range in TextView using Swift

Tags: swift, hyperlink, textview, range, nsmutableattributedstring

I am using attributed text string in Swift inside a textview, once I add a link attribute to the textview, whatever user writes after that link attribute it will be still as a link attribute and not a normal attribute, so here I can fix the problem with adding a separator(adding a normal attribute) after my link attribute, but the problem is I cannot add any separator because I want to use it as an url.

```
attributeString.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributeString.length))
```

[please see this image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itBso.png)
the word test2 still has the link attribute

Comment: Maybe by updating the `typingAttributes` of the `UITextView`?

Comment: @Larme Thanks a lot it worked! after adding my attributes I used `typingAttributes` and also I used it inside `shouldChangeTextIn` delegate for keeping this even when user deletes characters.